# How do I add Ruby methods to a rake file 'the right way'?

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm creating a complicated Rakefile, and have some logic which is used in various places, and want to package it up in some 'helper' methods. I see three possibilities:

1. Put the methods after the tasks that invoke them.
2. Put them in a separate `rake_helpers.rb` file and include that at the start.
3. Use some rake feature I don't know about to handle just that case.

What's the best practice or convention here?

Comment: Do you mean helper methods for your rails application to use at run time? Or are they tools that you are using as part of development? Rake tasks are usually used for command line work as part of the development process. For application helpers, some might go under `app/helpers` for view/controller specific helpers. Otherwise, consider defining helper classes in files under `lib/extensions` for example.

Comment: I was using the term 'helper' generically. They actually are methods that are called in more than one Rakefile task, so putting the code inline would be not DRY. And ugly.

Comment: Indeed, I would not advocate putting them "inline". My comment indicates general location depending upon what role they play. DRYness is a detail below that. If they're objects used by several Rake tasks, you can still put them under `lib`, either in separate `.rb` files in the same folder as the Rakefiles, or in a different `lib` subfolder. Your config file may need to indicate the existence of any new lib paths you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stick them in a `lib/rake` subdirectory, and only include them for the purpose of the rake tasks. If I need to, I can also separately include those files in my Rails (or whatever else) environment.

I actually have a whole library of special functions like this. When I'm not using Rails, for example, I have my own `say_with_time("message") do; block; end` logger.